# Error añadiendo mensaje MIMEMultipart en bandeja de enviados

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

Estoy realizando el envío de un correo con adjuntos utilizando smtplib y cuando realizo el envío del correo, quiero mandar este correo a la bandeja de Elementos enviados, estoy append de imaplib y me devulve este error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
Exception Location: c:\python35\lib\imaplib.py in append, line 383
```

El código que uso para enviar el email y luego crearlo en Elementos enviados es:

```
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'I have a picture'
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(targets)
    idEmail = email.utils.make_msgid()
    msg['Message-id'] = idEmail
    if len(cc) > 0:
        msg['Cc:'] = ', '.join(cc)  
    txt = MIMEText('I just bought a new camera.')
    msg.attach(txt)
    # añadir adjuntos
    for adjunto in adjuntos:
        with open(adjunto, 'rb') as f:
            x = MIMEApplication(f.read())
        x.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(adjunto))
        msg.attach(x)
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, targets+cc+bcc, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

    server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.1and1.es', 993)
    server.login(username, password)
    m = msg.as_string()
    server.append('"Elementos enviados"', '',  imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), m)
```

Os agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que está solucionado, solo he tenido que cambiar este detalle:

```
server.append('"Elementos enviados"', '',  imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), m.encode('utf-8')
```